# Can you transmit file over wire while it is being created - Parallel Operation?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

I intend to copy a file over LAN, while it is being created. Lets say a 500MB file is being written using StreamWriter. Can we do copy the file once every 100MB has been written.

What feature of the framework C# async, or LINQ.Parallel .. Can help me to achieve this.

Comment: Do you *need* to write the file to disk at the same time?

Comment: Are you writing with StreamWriter per byte or StreamWriter writes multiple (all) bytes at the time?

Comment: Do you need a file-on-disk as a result at all?

Comment: @spender StreamWriter woudld write one object at a time. using sw.Write(objectInstance), and the data to be written is array of this object.

Comment: @GregorPrimar I am not writing all array instances at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be acheived with what's known as a tee stream. [EchoStream](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3922/EchoStream-An-Echo-Tee-Stream-for-NET) looks like it would do the trick. Set up your StreamWriter to write to the EchoStream and have that write to both a NetworkStream and a FileStream, or 2 FileStreams (or whatever).